# CSS isn't loading

Tags: html, css

Last night I finished styling my header for my website. It looked exactly like it should to the pixel.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3Tg60F1.png]

But when I opened my work this morning, it looked like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WaX7Ws6.png]

No changes to the code were made, and all files and images are as they should be. (Actually, my only change was turning "Home, Work, Info, Contact" into text instead of using their images.

Here's my code:

```
<header>
    <div class="containter">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            <a class="nav-logo" href="index.html">
                <img class="nav-logo" src="img/logoF.png" alt="Logo" height="94">
            </a> 
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html"><img class="name-layout" src="img/HeaderName.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
            <div class="container social-layout">
                <a class="social-media" href="#"><img src="img/FaceBook.png" alt="FB"></a>
                <a class="social-media" href="#"><img src="img/Twitter.png" alt="TW"></a>
                <a class="social-media" href="#"><img src="img/Instagram.png" alt="IG"></a>
                <a class="social-media" href="#"><img src="img/YouTube.png" alt="YT"></a>
            </div>
        </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And my css

```
/*
Main Website
Author: Jaime Wissner
version: 1.0
*/
/* Base- Base styles, variables, mixins... */
/* line 2, ../scss/base/_base.scss */
.layout-blue {
  background-image: url(img/Background.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

/* line 7, ../scss/base/_base.scss */
.layout-banner {
  height: 96px;
}

/* Modules - Individual site components */
/* Layout - Page layout */
/* line 1, ../scss/layouts/_nav.scss */
.nav-logo {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

/* line 6, ../scss/layouts/_nav.scss */
.navbar-nav {
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-left: 0;
}

/* line 11, ../scss/layouts/_nav.scss */
.nav-links {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "trajan-sans-pro", sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
}

/* line 18, ../scss/layouts/_nav.scss */
.top-bar {
  height: 136px;
  width: auto;
  background-image: url(img/Header.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

/* line 24, ../scss/layouts/_nav.scss */
.social-media {
  padding: 5px;
}

/* line 28, ../scss/layouts/_nav.scss */
.name-layout {
  margin-top: -15px;
}

/* line 36, ../scss/layouts/_nav.scss */
.heading {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px #000000;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? or what happened? Obviously, I'm also using Bootstrap.

Update: I retyped the links to the images in my scss files, (didn't change it, just retyped it) and when it recompiled,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/drJus.png

I didn't change anything, but the Scout detected a change and recompiled. Is this a bug from SASS, or perhaps Scout?

Comment: Looks like your static files aren't loading. Check your console for 404 errors.

Comment: You're right. 404s down the board. But all the files are in their correct position.

Comment: Can't help much with what's in your question. Please edit and update with path info, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap files are not linked properly Jaime.

Whether you're using cdn links or you're using local source of the bootstrap files (bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js) make sure they are properly linked by checking from your console by pressing F12 in Chrome while you're in your webpage and click on `console`.

Check if any missing files error is shown there and correct them accordingly.